# Changes does not reflect on frontend magento 2 issue

Tags: magento2, orders, cache, chrome-browser

For temporary purpose, i have disabled all the 'Add to cart' options from my site, so that the customer cannot place the order.
I checked at my end, on desktop as well as on mobile, the Add to cart button is no more visible, hence, i was not able to place order.
But still, i am getting some order confirmations from customers end. How is this possible. How the customer's are able to place the order when there is no Add to cart button on the entire site.

My view is that, this is because of the customer's browser cache, my new changes are not reflected at there end. what can i do from magento site, that the changes get reflected at customer's end even there is previous browser cache.

Comment: There are multiple places where customer able to place the order, so you need to first confirm that you have disable that all options.

Comment: Which places you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 Customer are able to place the order into following places.

```
 1. Product Page.
 2. Wishlist Page
 3. Re-Order options
 4. Already Save Cart into customer account.
```

So confirm you restrict this all places.

Comment: it is disabled every where